# Extended list view: Show text input inside once clicked

Tags: android, android-layout, android-sdk-2.3

I am working on a UI where I have a list view. Each row has 2 information. One is Product name and the other is product ID stacked one over other. So each row has 2 lines of data.

What i want to do with this:

Once a user clicks on each row, it will further expand and show one input and one spinner. So it is basically for putting in Quantity and unit of measure.

Please let me know if this is achievable and if I can refer to some example.

What I need is more like

Taskos To Do List | Task List
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.taskos&hl=en

All i need is that the category will not be expandable. Only the items will be expandable. All i need is an example of such app and then I can take it forward.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  If one of the answers below helps you out, you should click on the check mark next to the answer.  This does two things:  1) it lets everyone know your issue has been resolved so they don't need to look at it 2) It gives credit to the person that helped you out.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* it could be done... you would need to put the extra widgets in your row layout, populate them and hide them upon list creation, then in your onListItemCLick you could unhide them.

Note I have no idea if this would work, but it seems reasonable that it might and it's what I would try and do to achieve the goal.

Answer (score 0):

[listView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) cannot be expanded. however you can use an [expandablelistView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html)

But the kind of functionality you want cannot be done this way(I guess.).

You can use

```
registerForContextMenu("your list View");
```

to register your list view

```
onCreateContextMenu
```

for the kind of action you want to be performed in your case its dialog with **EditText** and **Spinner** to have input from user